# Find the sum of $k/2^k, k=1$ to $n$

Tags: summation

Let $S=1/2+2/2^2+3/2^3+...+n/2^n$

I try searching on the internet and see only the version of $k=1$ to infinity. I put this equation on Wolfram Alpha and get $(2^{n+1}-n-2)/2^n$ but I dunno how to do that. Please help

Comment: "From $n=1$ to $n$"  Change the second one to something different like $N$, or change the indexing variable to something different like $k$.  The index and the bound should not be named the same.

Comment: you might find this interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145579/x-n-sum-k-1n-kak-convergence-and-limit

Comment: @edo that looks interesting but it is beyond my understanding for now hahah

Comment: Well, you know that you can write $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{1}{2}^k $ as something right? So apply the derivative on both sides and multiply with 1/2 on both sides.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence

Comment: It might help to differentiate a power series..

Comment: I've been doing several exercise about the sum but I never once differentiate it. I could say I dunno that it is possible hahaha

Comment: Well, its certainly possible for finite series.  For infinite series, some justification is in order which is done when exploring the topic of formal power series in greater depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of what is called an [arithmetico-goemetric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). We can write it more compactly as $$S_n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}$$

The common ratio for the denominators is $2$, so we will multiply the entire series by $2$:

\begin{align}
S_n &= \,\qquad\frac{1}{2} +\frac{2}{4} +\frac{3}{8} +\frac{4}{16} + \cdots + \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{n}{2^n}\tag{1}\\\\
2S_n&=\,\,1 +\frac{2}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{4}{8} +\frac{5}{16} +\cdots +\frac{n}{2^{n-1}} \qquad\tag{2}\\
\end{align}

Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$:

$$2S_n - S_n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}   \right) - \frac{n}{2^n}$$

Everything on the right hand side, except the last term, is a [finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) with common ratio $1/2$.

\begin{align}
S_n &= \left(2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right) - \frac{n}{2^n}\\\\
S_n &= \left(\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n}}-\frac{2}{2^{n}}\right) - \frac{n}{2^{n}}\\\\
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k} &= \boxed{\frac{2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{n}}}\\\\
\end{align}

---

The exact same method works even more cleanly for the corresponding infinite series. We can also take the limit of the partial sums:

$$S = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{n}}\right) = 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The most direct way is to replace $\frac12$ with general $a\ne1$ and consider the product:
$$
(1-a)^2\sum_{k=1}^n ka^k.
$$

You will find that the series telescopes with a simple result. In fact it is the same method which works with geometric series.