How to describe this identity in words?
Whenever I write an induction proof, I try to give it a word-description.  Sometimes it's hard to describe the identity proven.  This one, for example,
$$2\cdot1 + 3\cdot2 + 4\cdot2^2 + 5\cdot2^3 + \cdots + (n + 1) 2^{n - 1} = n 2^n$$
sounds like what?  I'm just saying the sum of the terms $(i + 1)2^{i - 1}$.  Can you think of a better way to describe this identity?  (I'm also pondering on why it is intuitively true, but that'd be a second question.)

Can we talk about a weighted geometric sum ?

It's a polynomial in $2$ of degree $n-1$ with the $i$-th term has coefficient $i+2$.

I liked both descriptions.  Thanks very much.  Either one works like a complete answer.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453281/16397

Thanks, @r.e.s.

It turns out that this type of sequence does have a name: the summands form an arithmetico-geometric sequence, and thus the sum can be called an arithmetico-geometric series.

Very nice.  Thanks for the addition.
