# How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n k*2^{n-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is it possible to calculate this sum in such a way that it only depends on n? $\sum_{k=1}^n k*2^{n-k}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
The derivative of $x^{k}$ of $kx^{k-1}$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

Take your sum and multiply by $2^{-n}$. Then you have 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{2^k}= \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{k}{2^k}
$$
There are many ways to compute this sum. For example, you could use Taylor Series. For a few ways, [see this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453281/find-the-sum-of-k-2k-k-1-to-n) or [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145579/x-n-sum-k-1n-kak-convergence-and-limit). Then simply multiply your final formula by $2^n$ to 'undo' the $2^{-n}$ you multiplied by in the beginning.